# how to assign one array into another

Tags: python, numpy

Hi i'm using numpy to create a couple of arrays and then put those into another one.

This is my code:

```
Array1 = np.empty([1,4])
a1 = np.zeros([filas, columnas])
a2 = np.zeros([filas, columnas])
a3 = np.zeros([filas, columnas])
a4 = np.zeros([filas, columnas])


Array1 [0, 0] = a1
Array1 [0, 1] = a2
Array1 [0, 2] = a3
Array1 [0, 3] = a4

print(Array1)
```

return is 'ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence'
any piece of advice would be very helpful.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `Array1` as created only has slots for 4 numbers.  It can't hold arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Array1 = np.empty([1,4,filas,columnas])
a1 = np.zeros([filas, columnas])
a2 = np.zeros([filas, columnas])
a3 = np.zeros([filas, columnas])
a4 = np.zeros([filas, columnas])
```

Your array is too small to hold the created arrays.

Comment: Thank you very much! solved my problem by using:    Array = np.empty([1,4,filas,columnas])

Comment: You're welcome, please mark the Answer as correct then.